# Transforming data for normality with negative values using python

Tags: normal-distribution, numpy

I am working with a data set in a machine learning project, which has lots to negative values. I want to transform the distribution of my data to normal. I tried using numpy.log, but since log is only for positive values, it is producing null values. So how should I approach this issue. Below is the distribution of my variable. Also, I am confused, whether I should normalize this distribution in the first place.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to transform your distribution to Normal?

Comment: @jbowman I am thinking it can lead to improved efficiency of my model.

Comment: Is it not already close enough to normal for most purposes?

Comment: @Micheal I think I can consider this as normal, however, I still would like to know how to deal with negative values, if I want to make the distribution normal.

Comment: Please consider an edit, I would like to what can be done for a variable has distribution something like the 1st image above.

Comment: Trying to take logarithms of negative numbers is a danger sign for your readers. You should revise this function to see why it makes no sense. You can’t usefully transform data like this, let alone “make” it normal. it is approximately symmetric to start with. But the clumping needs attention. It might reflect heterogeneity that is more of a problem for modeling than any lack of normality. There are transformations that cope with data that are both negative and positive— cube root and asinh spring to mind — but I doubt that either will help enough to be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need to make the distribution "Normal".   You don't really give details of what you're trying to do, so I will take the simplest case I can think of (simple linear regression).   You have $(y, x)$ pairs of data, and you are trying to predict $y$ from $x$.

The distribution or otherwise of $x$ is irrelevant and, depending on the assumptions you make, you may assume that the distribution of $y$ is *conditionally* Normal, i.e. there is a normal distribution around the line you fit, with the same variance for all fitted values of $y$.

Formally, you propose a model of the form $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$ and you actually assume that the errors $\epsilon$ are zero mean, constant variance Normal.   You can assess whether this is a plausible assumption by looking at the residuals, $y - \hat{y}$ (where $\hat{y}$ is the predicted value of $y$ given $x$ and your parameter estimates are $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$).

I know that's a lot of words, but I don't understand why you care whether your variable has a Normal distribution.  I've given the default reply. In most cases you don't particularly want or care about Normal distributions.  Your problem may be different, but if so, could you please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to z-transform your data, there is an easy implementation:

```
from scipy import stats
normalized_dataset = [stats.zscore(item) for item in dataset]
```

And yes, your AI might need standardized data! (if it doesn't standardize by itself)

Comment: This does not change the shape of the distribution and therefore does not appear to meet the objectives of the question.